# Word request for 'too grand to be explained'

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am looking for a word that means 'too powerful/grand to be explained in words.'

Sentence:

> He argued that passion was something inherent, an entity too intrinsic to be []

Compartmentalized/explained may work? Not really what I'm going for though.

This is based off of Eliot's quote:

> "It is obvious that we can no more explain a passion to a person who has never experienced it than we can explain light to the blind."

So if that helps to give context... :)

If an adequate word doesn't exist, I am thinking:

> He argued that passion was something inherent, an entity too intrinsic to be cinched into words.

or

> He argued that passion was something inherent, an entity too intrinsic to be cinched by words.

Which of these is more proper? Is there another phrase that would work better?

Comment: Inherent isn't the right idea, nor is intrinsic.  The point is more like trying to explain "blue" to someone who's totally color blind.

Comment: Please see  [this guidance from Stack Exchange Management](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2160/single-word-requests-crosswords-and-the-fight-against-mediocrity) about such questions. We are not a word-puzzle and crossword puzzle site; we're a site for linguists, etymologists, and serious English-language enthusiasts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the phrase "to beggar description."

> Merriam Webster defines it as:
>
> —used to talk about something that is very difficult to describe.

(Shakespeare too used it in Antony and Cleopatra)(2:2)

"For her own person, it beggared all description."(Source- The Free Dictionary)

Answer (score 0):

[ineffable](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/ineffable) works for your opening sentence with no added context - via Collins English Dictionary, "1) too great or intense to be expressed in words ... 3) indescribable; indefinable."

but it looks like you want variants for what comes after the "too", whereas 'ineffable' is literally "a word that means 'too powerful/grand to be explained in words.'"

as far as helping to construct a chewy sentence with the context and structure you presented:

- "too experiential to be encapsulated"?  (i.e. something to be experienced rather than shoehorned into second-hand talk)
- "too primordial to be verbalized"?  (i.e. too original or fundamental to be characterized by mere speech)

edited to add:

- "too visceral to be abstracted"?  (i.e. too closely related to instinct to be translatable in intellectual dimensions)

Comment: I love the phrases!

Comment: Please quote the relevant part from your link. Links break every so often, and answers should be as complete as possible in themselves. Also, please explain why *experiential* and *primordial* fit.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to find an exact word for your need. But close adjective is enigmatic.

Else, you could write as

> He argued that passion was something inherent, an entity too intrinsic to be inked in any script or enunciated in lucid words to the masses.